# Embed complex object in entity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, embeddable

I want to embed the following

```
 @Embeddable
  public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private UUID id;

  @CreatedDate
  @Column(name = "created_date", updatable = false)
  private LocalDateTime createdDate;

 }
```

into my room entity

```
    @Entity
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Table(name = "room")
    public class room {
    
      @EmbeddedId
      private BaseEntity baseEntity;
    
    
      @Column(length = 80, nullable = false)
      private String name;
}
```

So that my generated table looks like this

```
room
  id
  createdDate
  name
```

But id and createdDate are not getting embedded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of  `@Embeddable` just extend your `BaseEntity`

```
@MappedSuperclass 
@Getter
@Setter
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private UUID id;

  @CreatedDate
  @Column(name = "created_date", updatable = false)
  private LocalDateTime createdDate;

 }

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "room")
public class room extends BaseEntity{

  @Column(length = 80, nullable = false)
  private String name;

}
```